# Laravel on Shared Hosting unable to find path to files

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, shared-hosting

I was able to run my Laravel 5.3 application very well on my local machine. But when I upload it to the shared hosting, I have the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:View [welcome] not found.
```

I also observed that while on the online server, the application is looking for the files in the path they are on my local machine

I only have a shared hosting and so cannot run PHP Artisan commands. I have tried to

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and yet the problem persists.

I have even manually deleted all the files in storage/framework/views but the problem persists.

My local machine is a MAC OS with XAMPP with PHP 7 and my shared hosting is a CentOS Linus server with PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to clear the auto loader cache by running the following command on the server

```
composer dump-auto -o
```

Once the command has completed it will update the vendor autoload paths and the application should work correctly.

Comment: I don't have that level of access on the shared hosting. I have no access to the console

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your web route file

```
Route::get('/updateapp', function()
{
    exec('composer dump-autoload');
    echo 'composer dump-autoload complete';
});
```